# Continuity and discontinuity of this function

Tags: calculus, continuity

$$f(x)=[arctan(x)] $$
we are given this problem to check this function's continuity and find out where it's discontinuous , note that $[]$ donotes greatest integer function now the problem comes when we have to get that value of $arctan(x)$ which is $\ge 1$ and $\le -1$ now how do we go on to find out this?

Comment: The last part of your question makes no sense to me. Would you mind clarifying it?

Comment: @Rajath thanks i got it , it was my stupidity :P

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Greatest integer function is discontinuous at integer points. Therefore, the given function will be discontinuous when arctan(x) is an integer.